# map overlay not showing. How to show overlay?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show an overlay on the map but it not showing it. I copied this code from official documentation. What wrong going here. How can I resolve this issue? Is this code refreshing map once overlay is assigned? Is this code drawing an overlay on the map?

Code:

```js
var overlay;
function initMap() {
  USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 20,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        navigationControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        gestureHandling: 'cooperative',
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
          new google.maps.LatLng(62.281819, -150.287132),
          new google.maps.LatLng(62.400471, -150.005608)
      );

      var srcImage = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/' + 'javascript/examples/full/images/talkeetna.png';

      overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
}

function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
      this.image_ = image;
      this.map_ = map;

      this.div_ = null;

      this.setMap(map);
}

USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
      div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
      div.style.position = 'absolute';

      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = this.image_;
      img.style.width = '100%';
      img.style.height = '100%';
      img.style.position = 'absolute';
      div.appendChild(img);

      this.div_ = div;

      var panes = this.getPanes();
      panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
}

USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
      var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());
      var div = this.div_;
      div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
      div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
      div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
      div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
}

USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
      this.div_ = null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gmaps.js/0.4.25/gmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map" data-map-zoom="9"></div>
```

Error:

> this.setMap is not a function

Live Demo:

https://www.vsss.co.in/Right/

Comment: Please give example site url or documentation.

Comment: @MohitGupta Question updated

Comment: have you defined `setMap` anywhere? Because `USGSOverlay` is your function, this.setMap of this should be defined by you.

Comment: @dabishan No I not defined it. even not defined on documentation. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

Answer (score 0):

You missed this part on the top :

```
      var overlay;
      USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
```

this will give you setMap and other functions from OverlayView